# Magento 2: Internal error : Huge input lookup when Configurable Product on click edit

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1

I added one configurable product with 2000 variations so when i click on edit main product to view in admin page return

```
Warning: DOMDocumentFragment::appendXML(): Entity: line 1: parser error : internal error: Huge input lookup in /var/www/html/test1/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Xhtml/Template.php on line 60
```

so please help me, It is serious problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override below Magento class to fix this problem.

```
/var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Xhtml/Template.php
```

method public function append($content) must be changed to:

```
$target=$this->templateNode->ownerDocument;

$source = new \DOMDocument();
$source->loadXml($content, LIBXML_PARSEHUGE);

$this->templateNode->appendChild(
    $target->importNode($source->documentElement, TRUE)
);
```

Also, you can change

```
public function __construct and add 'LIBXML_PARSEHUGE'
$document->loadXML($content, LIBXML_PARSEHUGE);
```

> Reference: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8084#issuecomment-335239220

**Hope it helps!!!**